# jQuery click function not attaching correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write a reusable bit of code for attaching scroll-to click events to various DOM nodes by using data attributes. Here's what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<li class="scroll-to-anchor" data-dest='top'></li>

<div id='top'></div>
```

**JS**

```
if ($('.scroll-to-anchor').length) {
    $('.scroll-to-anchor').each(function () {
        var instance = $(this);
        if ($(this).attr('data-dest')) {
            var destination = $(this).data('dest');
            if ($('#' + destination).length) {
                instance.click(function () {
                    alert('click');
                    // Scroll to destination
                })
            } else {
                throw 'Not a valid scroll-to anchor'
            }
        } else {
            throw 'No data attribute present'
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, the function is supposed to:

1. Check if any .scroll-to-anchor nodes exist
2. If they do, run them through an each
3. Check if .scroll-to-anchor has a data-dest attribute
4. If it does, check that the attribute corresponds to a DOM node
5. If it does, attach the click event

Everything is working fine, but the click event isn't attaching. I have a feeling this is scope related, but I can't figure it out...

Comment: So you have an element with ID top at time you check it? ANyway, you have to provide MCVE replicating issue

Comment: @A.Wolff Yup, else it will throw the error.

Comment: you dont have to use loops to attaching any events with jquery. You can bind it directly with the classname.

Comment: So your issue comes from somewhere we cannot be aware of... http://jsfiddle.net/82ruonf1/  Provide MCVE

Comment: @A.Wolff I am using this inside an AMD module and also using greensock etc so it's quite complicated. I removed the two `else { throw error }` bits and it seems to be working fine now, does throwing an error cause a loop to stop?

Comment: @JohnDoe Ya, of course...

Comment: Also, the first (outer) if is redundant since the .each() will iterate over the existing matched elements, and if there are no matching elements, it won't run the function inside it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`throw` may breaks your loop.
You may want to use `console.error()` instead.

```
$(".scroll-to-anchor").each(function() {
    var instance = $(this),
        destination = instance.data('dest'),
        element = $("#" + destination);

    if (destination) {
        if (element) {
            instance.on("click", function() {
                console.info("Anchor clicked");
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: element.offset().top
                }, 500);
            });
        } else {
            console.error("Destination not found");
        }
    } else {
        console.error("No destination specified");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ronency/1deu7fs1/)

**HTML**

```
<a id="top"></a>
<div class="scroll-to-anchor" data-dest="top">sdlkjfs</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.scroll-to-anchor').each(function () {
    var instance = $(this);
    if (instance.data('dest')) {
        var destination = instance.data('dest');
        if ($('#' + destination).length) {
            instance.click(function () {
                alert('click');
                // Scroll to destination
            })
        } else {
            throw 'Not a valid scroll-to anchor'
        }
    } else {
        throw 'No data attribute present'
    }
});
```